# Save an uploaded image in a local location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, upload

on my webpage an user can upload a image with an input like this:

```
<input ID="submitBackground" class="imageUploader" type='file'/>
```

The image shall be saved to my server to `C:/TEMP` immediately.
I try to get access to the uploaded file, I am so far:

```
var input = document.getElementById('submitBackground');
$("#submitBackground").change(function() {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            // Something (a stream?) is written in e.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
});
```

I just don't know how to continue, I need to save it local somehow.
Has anyone an idea how to do it?

Comment: What language are you using server-side to save the image?

Comment: Hello, I am using Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution now.  I am using this example: http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/22/jax-rs-resteasy-file-upload-html-form-example/

Works fine, now saving local is possible.